# Crash And Unexpected Behaviour On Popover And Sheet inside NavigationSplitView

Tags: macos, swiftui

After hours of trying to figure out where the crash was coming from I finally found that if you have a NavigationSplitView with combination of NavigationStack and you try to display a popover or a sheet (not in the root level, but inside any view that you push onto the NavigationPath) it will either cause an unexpected behaviour or crash the app. (Tested on Xcode beta 3 and 2, this only happens on macOS, works fine on iPadOS)

I simplified my app as much as I could and uploaded it to GitHub:

https://github.com/shutupdevon/IssueTest

The crash happens only when there is NavigationSplitView present, works fine if there's only NavigationStack. Another weird thing that I noticed was that if you started the app with the sidebar hidden and then tried to display a popover/sheet on the root view the sidebar expands by itself.

Could this be a bug or am I missing something?

Crash:

```
2022-10-14 21:50:15.886600+0400 IssueTest[16220:537280] [General] The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in Window pass, but it has already had more Update Constraints in Window passes than there are views in the window. 
<SwiftUI.AppKitWindow: 0x15d023de0> 0xa0d (2573) {{830, 361}, {900, 584}} en Future marking as needing Update Constraints in Window might be ignored.
2022-10-14 21:50:15.893015+0400 IssueTest[16220:537280] [General] The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in Window pass, but it has already had more Update Constraints in Window passes than there are views in the window. 
<SwiftUI.AppKitWindow: 0x15d023de0> 0xa0d (2573) {{830, 361}, {900, 584}} en
2022-10-14 21:50:15.896399+0400 IssueTest[16220:537280] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fab4418 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019f5feea8 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fab42bc +[NSException exceptionWithName:reason:userInfo:] + 0
    3   AppKit                              0x00000001a2cc0d04 -[NSWindow(NSDisplayCycle) _postWindowNeedsUpdateConstraintsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 1844
    4   AppKit                              0x00000001a2caaddc -[NSView _informContainerThatSubviewsNeedUpdateConstraints] + 64
    5   AppKit                              0x00000001a2caaddc -[NSView _informContainerThatSubviewsNeedUpdateConstraints] + 64
    6   AppKit                              0x00000001a2caaddc -[NSView _informContainerThatSubviewsNeedUpdateConstraints] + 64
    7   AppKit                              0x00000001a2caaddc -[NSView _informContainerThatSubviewsNeedUpdateConstraints] + 64
    8   AppKit                              0x00000001a2caaddc -[NSView _informContainerThatSubviewsNeedUpdateConstraints] + 64
    9   AppKit                              0x00000001a2caad60 -[NSView setNeedsUpdateConstraints:] + 460
    10  AppKit                              0x00000001a3699a10 -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayoutInternal) _prepareForTwoPassConstraintsUpdateIfNeeded] + 364
    11  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d15790 -[NSView updateConstraints] + 24
    12  SwiftUI                             0x00000001c75be970 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_11 + 53928
    13  SwiftUI                             0x00000001c75be99c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_11 + 53972
    14  AppKit                              0x00000001a345c8d0 ___NSViewUpdateConstraints_block_invoke + 88
    15  AppKit                              0x00000001a2cd2700 NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange + 108
    16  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d1576c _NSViewUpdateConstraints + 96
    17  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d1549c -[NSView _updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeededCollectingViewsWithInvalidBaselines:] + 692
    18  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d210dc __82-[NSView _updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeededCollectingViewsWithInvalidBaselines:]_block_invoke + 228
    19  CoreAutoLayout                      0x00000001a770a514 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 88
    20  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d152b0 -[NSView _updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeededCollectingViewsWithInvalidBaselines:] + 200
    21  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d15358 -[NSView _updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeededCollectingViewsWithInvalidBaselines:] + 368
    22  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d15358 -[NSView _updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeededCollectingViewsWithInvalidBaselines:] + 368
    23  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d15358 -[NSView _updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeededCollectingViewsWithInvalidBaselines:] + 368
    24  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d15358 -[NSView _updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeededCollectingViewsWithInvalidBaselines:] + 368
    25  AppKit                              0x00000001a3452980 __45-[NSView updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeeded]_block_invoke_2 + 52
    26  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d15068 __45-[NSView updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 224
    27  AppKit                              0x00000001a2cd2700 NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange + 108
    28  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d14f7c -[NSView updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeeded] + 96
    29  AppKit                              0x00000001a36a0088 -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayoutInternal) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 172
    30  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d35e88 __NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserverForUpdateConstraints_block_invoke + 364
    31  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d35ce8 NSDisplayCycleObserverInvoke + 168
    32  AppKit                              0x00000001a2d35944 NSDisplayCycleFlush + 644
    33  QuartzCore                          0x00000001a7081bb0 _ZN2CA11Transaction19run_commit_handlersE18CATransactionPhase + 120
    34  QuartzCore                          0x00000001a7080930 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 324
    35  AppKit                              0x00000001a2db7bc4 __62+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]_block_invoke + 272
    36  AppKit                              0x00000001a3494760 ___NSRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler_block_invoke + 64
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fa38de4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fa38cd0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 532
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fa38308 __CFRunLoopRun + 784
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fa378a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
    41  HIToolbox                           0x00000001a90ae3bc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    42  HIToolbox                           0x00000001a90ae200 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 672
    43  HIToolbox                           0x00000001a90adf48 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
    44  AppKit                              0x00000001a2c8f664 _DPSNextEvent + 632
    45  AppKit                              0x00000001a2c8e7f4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 728
    46  AppKit                              0x00000001a2c82c24 -[NSApplication run] + 464
    47  AppKit                              0x00000001a2c5a08c NSApplicationMain + 880
    48  SwiftUI                             0x00000001c63c805c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 8244
    49  SwiftUI                             0x00000001c75b1784 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_11 + 188
    50  SwiftUI                             0x00000001c6df09c8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 136
    51  IssueTest                           0x00000001049c6de8 $s9IssueTest0aB3AppV5$mainyyFZ + 40
    52  IssueTest                           0x00000001049c6f80 main + 12
    53  dyld                                0x000000019f62fe50 start + 2544
)
```

Comment: Any word or solution found on this?

Comment: I am running into same issue and it is not fixed on MacOS 13.2 beta.  Did anyone file a bug report with Apple?

I am replacing my popover with an .overlay on MacOS now - but not what I want to have in long run.

Comment: @KlausThul I've ran into this bug myself and reported it to Apple.

Comment: I'm getting the same exact crash when I select a `List` item in the 2nd and 3rd pane of my 3-pane NavigationView (I can't use NavigationSplitView because I'm not targeting 13.0+ yet) and then try to arrow-key up or down to select an adjacent item. i mean, that's not all i'm doing. i have written some of the worst SwiftUI abusing code in the world.

Comment: Update: Hmm, I fixed the crashing by replacing a `NavigationLink(tag:selection:destination:label)` with a `NavigationLink(destination:label)`.